# How to hide QuickType from Keyboard in React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native, quicktype

Is it possible to hide QuickType from keyboard in TextInput ?
[image: This]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling autocorrect also removes the QuickType suggestions:

```
 <TextInput
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
   value={this.state.text}
   autoCorrect={false}
 />
```